# Cassandra bootstrap fails with "unable to fetch range"

Tags: cassandra, bootstrapping

I operate a 4 node cassandra 1.2.6 cluster. Recently, there were some problems with two nodes, so I decided to add a fifth node just to be safe. I've joined the ring, and the bootstrap process initiated, but after some time, a following error occurs:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to fetch range [(56713727820156410577229101238628035242,113427455640312821154458202477256070484], (113427455640312821154458202477256070484,1276058875953519237 98765477786913079296]] for keyspace xxxxxxxx from any hosts

Bootstrap never finishes, and the service stops. If restarted, bootstrap begins again, and goes in circles.

All other nodes bootstrapped fine until now, and repeating the process (clearing the directories and reinitializing) didn't help. There might be more nodes coming, so I'd like to be able to bootstrap cleanly, and I haven't found any resources on this particular error.

Any hints or experiences? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you waiting 2 minutes between starting nodes up and what OS are you using?

Comment: I've waited several hours between startups, and it didn't help. OS is Ubuntu Linux 12.04.

Update: The issue has resolved itself, I've noticed that this time streaming went from another node, and finished without any issues. Though, I would like to get a clue  what actually happened here, and should I expect problems later on..

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have "holes" in your ring from failed nodes.  Check with `nodetool ring`, and any nodes marked Down that aren't actually part of the cluster anymore can be removed with `nodetool removetoken` (may need the `force` flag).

Comment: Hi jbellis, thanks for the suggestion. At the moment of bootstrap, all four nodes were reported as "up". Shouldn't have consistency mechanisms used nodes that were up to fill in holes (assuming they existed)?

Comment: Hmm.  I'm actually not sure what that message means then.  Streaming was rewritten to be more robust in 2.0 (http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/streaming-in-cassandra-2-0) so you may want to upgrade.  In particular I note that this message no longer appears in the 2.0 source.